# Android WebView unable to load URL in one activity but loads in another

Tags: android, webview

I have a ListView and on click on an item, a new Activity is called by delivering am intent. All the activities have a single webview and load a different url or different parts in the same url (different div elements of the same url).

The problem I am facing is that only one of the Activity loads the url in the webview, the rest show a blank white webview. Can this be a problem with Jsoup??

Also note that when I run only the Jsoup code to fetch data and output to console, it works; but not when I use it within the activity.

Below is code of both the activities (they just differ in a single line in `doc.select()`). Activity 1 works perfectly fine and displays the html in the webview, while Activity 2 shows a blank screen.

**Activity 1:**

```
public class Article extends Activity {

ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
WebView wv;

private static final int SUCCESS = 1;
private static final int NETWORK_ERROR = 2;
private static final int ERROR = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.article);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);

    new getHtml().execute();
}

private class getHtml extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    Elements tfa;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Article.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Wikipedia");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading today's featured article...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(MainActivity.url).get();

            tfa = doc.select("div#mp-tfa");
            return SUCCESS;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.e("Unknown Host Exception", "Network error", e);
            return NETWORK_ERROR;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IO Exception", "Failed to load HTML", e);
            return ERROR;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "An exception occured", e);
            return ERROR;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        if (result == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Network connection error. Check your internet connection and try again.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (result == 3) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Unknown error. Failed to load wikipedia.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (result == 1) {
            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            String tfa_html = tfa.outerHtml();
            tfa_html = tfa_html.replaceAll("a href=\"/wiki/",
                    "a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/");
            tfa_html = tfa_html.replaceFirst(
                    "src=\"//upload.wikimedia.org/",
                    "src=\"http://upload.wikimedia.org/");
            wv.loadData(tfa_html, "text/html", null);
        }

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && wv.canGoBack()) {
        wv.goBack();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

}
```

**Activity 2:**

```
public class Article extends Activity {

ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
WebView wv;

private static final int SUCCESS = 1;
private static final int NETWORK_ERROR = 2;
private static final int ERROR = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.article);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);

    new getHtml().execute();
}

private class getHtml extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    Elements tfa;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Article.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Wikipedia");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading today's featured article...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(MainActivity.url).get();

            tfa = doc.select("div#mp-tfp");
            return SUCCESS;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.e("Unknown Host Exception", "Network error", e);
            return NETWORK_ERROR;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IO Exception", "Failed to load HTML", e);
            return ERROR;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "An exception occured", e);
            return ERROR;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        if (result == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Network connection error. Check your internet connection and try again.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (result == 3) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Unknown error. Failed to load wikipedia.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (result == 1) {
            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            String tfa_html = tfa.outerHtml();
            tfa_html = tfa_html.replaceAll("a href=\"/wiki/",
                    "a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/");
            tfa_html = tfa_html.replaceFirst(
                    "src=\"//upload.wikimedia.org/",
                    "src=\"http://upload.wikimedia.org/");
            wv.loadData(tfa_html, "text/html", null);
        }

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && wv.canGoBack()) {
        wv.goBack();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem, the problem was the page stripped content off when loaded from a mobile browser/app. That was the reason of this problem. Just for information, the URL was `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page` which redirected to the mobile version of wikipedia.

The solution I found out was either to fetch data from separate wiki pages instead of picking from the main page or use `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Main_Page` as the URL, as this doesn't redirect to the mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

activity 1:
...
 tfa = doc.select("div#mp-tfa");
...

activity 2:
...
tfa = doc.select("div#mp-tfp");
...

is differrent.

maybe the response of MainActivity.url is not the node of "div#mp-tfp". only exist the node of  "div#mp-tfa".

Comment: I had mentioned that when I run it in a separate java program, jsoup prints the output of that div to the console. That node exists.

Comment: Log.i("ARTICLE DATA FETCH", tfa_html.substring(0, 30));

Comment: the len of tfa_html (the node of "div#mp-tfp") >= 30 ?

Comment: maybe tfa_html exists the spec char . eg '#' '%' ...  change the method loadData to other. eg loadbasexxx

Comment: That I had just added as a check; and if its <30 the app would crash with a runtime error; so that's not a problem

Comment: The encoding parameter specifies whether the data is base64 or URL encoded. If the data is base64 encoded, the value of the encoding parameter must be 'base64'. For all other values of the parameter, including null, it is assumed that the data uses ASCII encoding for octets inside the range of safe URL characters and use the standard %xx hex encoding of URLs for octets outside that range. For example, '#', '%', '\', '?' should be replaced by %23, %25, %27, %3f respectively.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: Jsoup.connect(MainActivity.url).get();  MainActivity.url is not deal with http status 301 or 302? "the response of MainActivity.url is not the node of "div#mp-tfp" " is right!